# Stack Overflow Teams filter posts with regular expression

Tags: support, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have a need to prevent users from posting with personal information (phone numbers, social security numbers, etc.).  Optimally as admin I want to apply a regular expression to each post before it is posted to prevent the post prior to posting.  Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt you can stop people from posting that.  Accidents happen, leaks take place, and people assume all kinds of safe things with a form on the Internet backed by a padlock.  Since it's a team, your company should already have a policy in place backed by training to ensure that your team members are at least trained on *what* PII they can't share in certain areas.  That's not a thing that anything technical is going to be able to fix.

Comment: We have this same issue on the main site, some people always manage to publish private keys, personal information and the like due to carelessness, ignorance or just plain old accidents. The only real fix is education and training. At least though in a team, the impact is a little more limited then here in public.

Comment: Could you regularly poll the [Teams API](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000154987-stack-overflow-for-teams-read-api) to look for posts that you think might contain PII? It won't catch all of it, but you'll be able to get some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to filter posts in the way you've describing using the Teams interface, nor is that currently on our roadmap of features we're looking to implement.

That said, Ben is correct, this could theoretically be accomplished via the API but only if you upgrade to the Business tier of Teams. Basic teams only have access to the read API.